# Asp.net passing string value from view to controller using jQuery time picker plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, timepicker

So I am using jQuery Time picker plugin from [here](https://github.com/senthilraj/TimePicki). When I pick the time in my view (ex: 11:48 PM) and submit it in debug mode, I don't see the value being passed to the controller. It is always a null value. I assume that I have problem in my code here, but can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MonStart, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control time_element", @name = "timepicker", @id = "monStart" } })
```

Model:

```
public string MonStart { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@model test.Models.Employee

@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })     

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MonStart, "Monday: ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MonStart, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control time_element", @name = "timepicker", @id = "monStart" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MonStart, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })              
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/timepicki.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/timepicki.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {         
        $("#monStart").timepicki();     
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: Do not use `@name = "timepicker"` - its does nothing (and recommend you do not use `@id = "monStart"` - its already `id="MonStart"` so use `$("#MonStart")` or `$('.time_element'). What does `$("#monStart").val()` return after you select a value?

Comment: hmm good point, so I changed it to $("#MonStart") or $('.time_element'), but still it is null. There is no $("#monStart").val()`? Are you talking abt $("#monStart").timepicki(); ?

Comment: I'm saying, add a temporary button in your view, handle its click event and check what `var time = $("#MonStart").val();` returns - is it what you expect?

Comment: just did it and i get what i want to get:
time = "02 : 37 : AM"

Comment: got it I was not binding it, dumb mistake. Thanks for your effort.